# Tables are not joining properly in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, join

I have to show result from the `dbo.mail_Messages` table, but the problem is that `Messages` should be shown which Ids are not in `dbo.mail_Reply`. For that I am using the query below but it is showing nothing.

I have also attached a screen shot:

[image]

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
SELECT
    dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID,
    dbo.mail_Users_Messages_Mapped.PlaceHolderID,
    IsRead,
    SenderId,
    dbo.mail_Messages.Subject,
    dbo.mail_Messages.Body,
    dbo.mail_Messages.Date,UserEmail
FROM
    dbo.mail_Users_Messages_Mapped
JOIN
   dbo.mail_Messages ON dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID = dbo.mail_Users_Messages_Mapped.MessageID
JOIN
   dbo.mail_Users ON dbo.mail_Users.UserID = dbo.mail_Users_Messages_Mapped.UserId
JOIN
   dbo.mail_Reply ON dbo.mail_Reply.MessageID = dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID
WHERE
   UserEmail = 'user1'
   AND dbo.mail_Users_Messages_Mapped.PlaceHolderId = 1
   AND dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID != dbo.mail_Reply.MessageID
```

Comment: `mail_reply` is not joined conditionally to `mail_users`, so you are getting a kind of Cartesian join once you add the `mail_reply` table to join.

Comment: May you show me any example query? Please, because I am not getting what you are trying to say...

Comment: Take a look at this example and pay attention to the join conditions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db40c/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will produce an empty result as it has two contradicting conditions. In the `join` clause you demand that:

```
dbo.mail_Reply.MessageID = dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID
```

And in the `where` clause you demand that

```
dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID != dbo.mail_Reply.MessageID
```

Since a value cannot be both equal and not equal to another value, the combination of these two conditions is an empty result.

One way to solve this, if I understand the requirements correctly, is to stop `join`ing `mail_Reply`, and use the `in` operator instead:

```
SELECT
dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID,
dbo.mail_Users_Messages_Mapped.PlaceHolderID,
IsRead,
SenderId,
dbo.mail_Messages.Subject,
dbo.mail_Messages.Body,
dbo.mail_Messages.Date,UserEmail
FROM
dbo.mail_Users_Messages_Mapped
join
dbo.mail_Messages on dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID = dbo.mail_Users_Messages_Mapped.MessageID
join
dbo.mail_Users on dbo.mail_Users.UserID = dbo.mail_Users_Messages_Mapped.UserId
where
UserEmail = 'user1'
and
dbo.mail_Users_Messages_Mapped.PlaceHolderId = 1
and
dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID NOT IN (SELECT MessageID FROM dbo.mail_Reply)
```